# $\mathcal{L}^N(B_r(x)\cap E)> 0 \hspace{0.6cm} \forall r>0$ if every point is a Lebesgue Point

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Exercise:** Let $E$ be a Borel set such that every point is a Lebesgue Point for $\chi_E$
, and let $x \in \partial E$ (the topological boundary).

Show that $\mathcal{L}^N(B_r(x)\cap E)> 0$, and $\mathcal{L}^N(B_r(x)\setminus E)> 0$ $\hspace{1cm}$ $\forall r>0$.

**Attempt:** First of all I don't get if $\chi_E(x)$ is meant to be $1$ or 0. Anyway, since $E$ is $\mathcal{L}^N$-misurable, thanks to the Lebesgue-Besicovitch Differentiation Theorem applied to $\chi_E$, we get

$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\mathcal{L}^N(B_r(x)\cap E)}{\mathcal{L}^N(B_r(x))}=1$

for every $x \in E$ and thus $\mathcal{L}^N(B_r(x)\cap E)> 0 \hspace{0.6cm} \forall r>0$. I didn't use the Lebesgue Points hypothesis and the second request is unsolved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ is just assumed to be a boundary point for $E$, and $E$ might be open or closed or neither, so  you don't know whether $\chi_E(x)$ is $0$ or $1$.  Fortunately, you don't need to know.

Given $r > 0$, since $x \in \partial E$ there are $y,z \in B_{r/2}(x)$ with $y \in E$ and $z \in E^c$.  Consider your quotients with $x$ replaced by $y$ and $z$...

Comment: ok I got it!! :)